# in JavaScript which of these 3 examples has best performance

Tags: javascript, object, closures, prototype

These three functions/objects can be used for the same purpose, I will be creating new instances of each object. I will be creating 1000 of each so I would like to know which one has the best performance.

```
jelly1 = new JellyFish();
jelly2 = new JellyFish2();
jelly3 = new JellyFish3();


//jellyfish object 3
function JellyFish3() {
    this.color = "blue";
    this.size = "medium";
    this.move = function (direction) {
        console.log("moving to " + direction);
        return direction;
    };
}

// jellyfish object 2
function JellyFish2() {};
// constructor
(function (instance) {
    instance.color = "blue";
    instance.size = "medium";
    instance.move = function (direction) {
        console.log("moving to " + direction);
        return direction;
    };
})(JellyFish2.prototype);

// jellyfish object 1
function JellyFish() {
    // constructor
    (function (instance) {
        instance.color = "blue";
        instance.size = "medium";
        instance.move = function (direction) {
            console.log("moving to " + direction);
            return direction;
        };
    })(JellyFish.prototype);
};
```

Comment: Benchmark it, for example with Benchmark.js (http://benchmarkjs.com/)

Comment: I guess `jellyfish object 2` has more performance ! as it sharing common prototype outside .  `constructor` each time calling memory will allocate

Comment: They do different things (and the last one, `JellyFish`, is quite useless), so why would you want to compare their performance?

Comment: Well, it doesn't so much matter which is faster when they don't do the same thing. `JellyFish2` makes every instance share the same `color` and `size` by placing them on the `prototype`. `JellyFish` shares the same trait as `JellyFish2`, but keeps modifying the values with each instance (but affected previous instances). That being said, "*best*" would probably be `JellyFish3` with `move` alone placed on the `prototype`.

Answer (score 2):

For Creating 50 constructors... JellyFish1 win ! http://jsperf.com/jellyfish

**For creating 50 instances... JellyFish2 win ! http://jsperf.com/jellyfish-instance**

Comment: I guess the test was supposed to create 1000 instances of the *same* constructor (if you could call `Jellyfish1` a "constructor"), not to create 1000 constructors.

Comment: Thanks for updating the test case at jsperf to 1000 it made the time difference much more obvious.